# JPA: Parent-Child relationship merge not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've been trying to model a rather simple parent-child relationship with JPA/Hibernate, and despite the amount of tutorials and posts on this, I haven't been able to get it to work.

I have a Customer entity with a numeric ID which has a list of Address entities. The Address entity has a composite key consisting of a foreign key on the customer ID and a sequential number to make it unique (but only in the context of a customer ID).

I want to be able to do classic CRUD operations on the Customer entity which should be reflected for the Address entities as well (for when I add, update or remove an address in the customer's list).

```
@Entity(name = "Customer ")
@Table(name = "customer ")
@DynamicUpdate
public class Customer implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Address> addresses;

    @Override public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return obj instanceof Customer && ((Customer ) obj).getId() == this.getId();
    }
}
```

-

```
@Entity(name = "Address")
@Table(name = "address")
@DynamicUpdate
public class Address implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "seqnumber", nullable = false)
    private Integer seqnumber;

    @Override public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return obj instanceof Address
            && ((Address) obj).getCustomer().equals(this.getCustomer())
            && ((Address) obj).getSeqNumber() == this.getSeqNumber();
    }
}
```

Creating a customer + addresses with javax.persistence.EntityManager.persist and retrieving a customer with javax.persistence.EntityManager.find has worked.
However I have not been able to update a customer with new/changed/deleted addresses when calling javax.persistence.EntityManager.merge.

```
// get data from REST service

// create customer entity - a customer with id 123 already exists in the db
Customer c = new Customer();
c.setId(123);

// create new address entity - no address with seqnumber 2 for customer 123 exists in db
Address a = new Address();
a.setCustomer(c); // or setCustomerId(123) when I tried unidirectional without the ManyToOne
a.setSeqNumber(2);
// add address to customer
c.getAddresses().add(a);

entityManager.merge(c);
```

I've tried a unidirectional OneToMany relationship with a list of addresses in the customer entity and only the customer-id with the address-sequential-number in the address entity. However when I removed an address from the list and added a new one instead, calling merge resulted in a insert into the address table with the composite keys being null (despite being set before the merge).

So I switched to a bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship and added a Customer object in the Address entity instead of the customer id (see class above). This meant I had to use the customer object instead of the customer-id in my equals method in the Address class, which resulted in a StackOverflowError.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to model this properly? Do I need to model the relationship differently? Is calling merge not the correct way?

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

---

UPDATE:
I finally found an answer on the Hibernate forum [here](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/merge-fails-with-composite-identifier-containing-association/191/4). It seems that the merge function can't (always) guarantee the behavior I'm looking for. Merge should be used for "re-attaching entities that got detached and not for taking arbitrary transient objects".
So instead of merge I simply got the existing entity via find and then updated the address list of the fetched existing entity to match my transient updated entity.